# ExtJS bind doesn't work on keyboard datefield change

Tags: extjs, extjs6, extjs6-classic

Here is the fiddle https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1dcv

The problem is that bind doesn't work when you change data in datefield using keyboard. Bind only works if you change date manually and then change focus to another element.

Here is the screenshot that shows the problem.

[image: datefield change]

Is it possible to fix this issue somehow or may be observe change event and set data to ViewModel manually? If manual data set is the solution what is the best way to do it?

Comment: It also works when I change the data using keyboard and then focus a different element (e.g. using tab key).

Comment: yes, it works after changing focus on tab press. But unfortunately does not on just simple change without focus change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think finally I have found the solution. Field has **valuePublishEvent** property:

**The event name(s) to use to publish the value Ext.form.field.Base#bind for this field.
Defaults to: [ 'select', 'blur' ]**

The solution is to change defaults to

```
valuePublishEvent: ['select', 'blur', 'change']
```